# Manual operation call in threaded-code interpreter (breaking normal flow)

Tags: c++, jvm, virtual-machine, interpreter, state-machine

Given is the following (shortened) threaded-code interpreter (finite state machine). It has a operation stack and a operand stack. On execution, the next operation is popped from the operation stack and executed.

There are three instructions:

- The *addition* instruction, which pops two operands from the operand stack, adds them and pushes the result on the operand stack
- The *print* instruction, which pops one operand from the operand stack and prints it out
- The *specialcall* instruction, which tries to manually call the *addition* instruction (from within the instruction) and needs to get the result of the calculation

Now the problem is, that in the specialcall method, the result of the calculation is needed, but after the addition operation was called in the instruction loop, further execution would simply continue right after the initial specialcall.

One approach would be to create a operation struct which contains a) the operation and b) the address where to jump back - if necessary. Then in the instruction loop, when the instruction struct is popped and the address is set, a jump to this address would be made right after the execution of the actual instruction.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

const uint32_t operation_addition = 1;
const uint32_t operation_print = 2;
const uint32_t operation_specialcall = 3;

std::deque<uint32_t> operations;
std::deque<uint32_t> stack;

void specialcall() {
    std::cout << "specialcall" << std::endl;

    // Manually create the call
    stack.push_back(52);
    stack.push_back(25);
    operations.push_back(operation_addition);

    // "place to jump back"

    // Need result of calculation here!
    ...
}

void addition() {
    std::cout << "addition" << std::endl;

    uint32_t operandA = stack.back();
    stack.pop_back();
    uint32_t operandB = stack.back();
    stack.pop_back();

    uint32_t result = operandA + operandB;
    stack.push_back(result);
}

void print() {
    std::cout << "print" << std::endl;

    uint32_t result = stack.back();
    stack.pop_back();

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}

void start() {
    while (!operations.empty()) {
        uint32_t op = operations.back();
        operations.pop_back();

        switch (op) {
        case operation_specialcall:
            specialcall();
            break;
        case operation_print:
            print();
            break;
        case operation_addition:
            addition();
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    stack.push_front(25);
    stack.push_front(53);
    operations.push_front(operation_addition);
    operations.push_front(operation_print);
    operations.push_front(operation_specialcall);
    start();

    std::cout << "execution finished" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have the result, it is on top of the stack.  After the code is executed.  So just retrieve it:

```
int main() {
    stack.push_front(25);
    stack.push_front(53);
    operations.push_front(operation_addition);
    operations.push_front(operation_print);
    operations.push_front(operation_specialcall);
    start();

    uint32_t result = stack.back();
    stack.pop_back();
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

If you need the result inside the operation_specialcall() function then you'll need to think deeply about how that function is going to use the result.  Arbitrarily, you could print it:

```
void specialcall() {
    stack.push_back(52);
    stack.push_back(25);
    operations.push_back(operation_addition);
    operations.push_back(operation_print);
}
```

Both approaches accomplish the exact same thing.  The key here is to distinguish compile-time from run-time.  Avoid getting them mixed up, that requires significant enhancements in your interpreter.  You'd have to implement the equivalent of an eval() function.  Which requires being able to manage multiple instruction streams, you don't have that plumbing in place.  In other words, you can't have the *operations* and *stack* variables as global variables anymore.

Comment: Thx for the reply! But the prob is a little more complicated. I should have pointed out from the start that the operations actually can not be altered at RT. Imagine theres a big array of opcodes, and all operations that need to be executed within the special-call method are predetermined. Now there is no possibility to tell the thread what to do after the execution of the operations within the specialcall method. One idea was to use setjmp and longjmp: In specialcall mark with setjmp - after calling return within the executed code call longjmp to get back. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I already mentioned an alternative in the last paragraph.  You need *another* set to operations+stack that you can start().  Recursing into start() isn't entirely impossible either but you'll at least provide a way to tell it where to start executing operations.  I actually think you are drastically on the wrong path with this.  This looks like a homework assignment that is trying to teach you the difference between compile-time and run-time.

Comment: Its not possible to create another Thread object with its own operations + stack, because the same Thread must be used. Lets apply this to Java's reflection: interpreted code calls native 'invoke' method -> vm retrieves invoked method and starts the execution within the _same_ thread -> once the invoked method has finished, the return value must be given back right to the specialcall-method. **but** if an exception occurs, the interpretation must _not_ continue right inside the specialcall, but simply let the thread continue its normal execution (within the operation iteration loop)...

Comment: Well, of course this is possible.  As I said, I think you are mis-interpreting your homework assignment.  You'll need a lot more operations if you want to emulate sub-routines like Java does, at least a CALL and RET and another stack to keep track of return addresses.

Comment: As I stated this is just a simplified example - all the other instructions are already there. This problem is applicable to other situations.. In the actual implementation there is a Frame object on the stack, which gets poped once all of its instructions are executed (a ret or throw comes). In this frame I could store the address where to jump back (right into specialcall), but this is imho dirty..